# Error pushing to remote with git

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, git

I have a fresh Centos 6 server stood up and I have installed git version 1.7.1 through yum.  I am using the smart http method through apache for access.

When I try to push to the remote server this is what I get:

```
$ git push origin master
Password:
Counting objects: 6, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 436 bytes, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
```

I have tried these things which made no difference:

- chown -R apache:apache /path/to/git/repository (httpd runs as apache)
- chown -R apache:users /path/to/git/repository
- chmod -R 777 /path/to/git/repository (obviously not secure but wanted to eliminate this being a file permission problem)

What can I try to get pushing to work?

Answer (score 2):

This may be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826639/repack-of-git-repository-fails.  I have seen similar errors when the repository is big (1-2GB) and I run out of memory on the server.  Specifically, the "git pack-objects" process on the servers eats up a lot of memory and processor time.

Solutions seem to include repacking the repository on the server:

```
git repack -a -d -f --window-memory 10m --max-pack-size 20m
```

Or adjusting the Git configuration on the server to reduce memory usage, such as:

```
git config pack.windowMemory 10m
git config pack.packSizeLimit 20m
```

You may need to play with the 10m and 20m values, depending on the amount of memory available.